# Class MyClaseName is implemented in both A.Framework and B.Framework

Tags: c++, ios, linker, ios-frameworks

I have iOS application which use frameworks A and B. Each of which requires `MyClaseName` class.

After running application I have following warnings in log:

> objc[2472]: Class MyClaseName is implemented in both
>   /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/workspace-amvqjwzykbswydebvpvdfbylgsck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.framework/A
>   and
>   /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/workspace-amvqjwzykbswydebvpvdfbylgsck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/B.framework/B.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I have checked following similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886321/class-x-is-implemented-in-both-y-and-z-one-of-the-two-will-be-used), but unfortunately this is not my case.

So, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think you may have to rename one of them.

Comment: You should rename them, is pretty important that when you create a class you use a sort of prefix. Usually I use my initial AF and name of the project or framework, for instance AFPhotogunViewController

Comment: @Yuchen, this class instances need to be the one for whole project. In case of renaming I will have different instances.

Comment: @IAmDav, this sounds very much like a **diamond inheritance** problem in `C++`. Not the same, but similar idea. Not sure whether there is really solution for your problem. Maybe you will still have to refactor your code structure.

Comment: hi @Yuchen, actually issue comes from iOS frameworks. my C++ classes loading twice. I think this Xcode need to introduce new option, to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reasoning behind prepending a specified prefix to all of the classes in your code.

A.framework's classes should be prefixed with AF, and B.framework should use BF, for example:

```
AFClassName *aInstance = [AFClassName new];
BFClassName *bInstance = [BFClassName new];
```

Without a prefix, both of these classes would effectively be called 'ClassName', and would lead to the kind of conflict you see.

Comment: How do you suggest to do that? write a script for all files to rename them? I hope there are some linker option to make app understand that is is the same object/class?